# Pygame displays as "not a package"

Tags: python, pygame

So i've installed pygame and confirmed the installation (aliens example).

I saved my script as `pygame.py`.

When I try to run my script I get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\*****>C:/Users/*****/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/*****/Downloads/pygame.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\*****\Downloads\pygame.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "c:\Users\*****\Downloads\pygame.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pygame.locals import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.locals'; 'pygame' is not a package
```

Anyone have this issue?

Comment: You've named your own script `pygame.py`, which is being imported instead of the actual module.  Rename it, and get rid of any file like `pygame.pyc` that was created in your Downloads folder.

Comment: No .pyc file was created in the folder

Comment: Also, pygame works now, but the windows always closes after a second of being opened.

Comment: I bet you're not setting up a game loop... https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/#basic-pygame-program

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] so it's possible to assist you.

Answer (score -1):

1. open Powershell
2. type "pip install pygame"
3. Hit enter

it will definietly help

Comment: That does legit nothing. Also what;s powershell?

Comment: press the start button and type 'powershell' and then follow the second step